# Return the data after _ from column in sql

Tags: sql-server

I have given values in Coulmn:

```
ABC_123  
123_ABCD  
1234_ABC
```

Expected Output:

```
123  
ABCD  
ABC
```

Return the data after "_"

Answer (score 2):

```
DECLARE @temp TABLE (val VARCHAR(50))
INSERT INTO @temp (val)
VALUES
    ('ABC_123'),
    ('123_ABCD'),
    ('1234_ABC')

SELECT SUBSTRING(val, CHARINDEX('_', val) + 1, LEN(val))
FROM @temp
```

results -

```
----------
123
ABCD
ABC
```